# Inverse by left multiplication but not right?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Suppose $T: V \rightarrow W$ and  $U: W \rightarrow V$ are linear transformations. It is known that $ U = T^{-1}$ if $UT = I_V$ and $TU = I_W$.

Is it possible to then also have a transform $Z: W \rightarrow V$ such that $ZT = I_V$ but $TZ \neq I_W$ (and likewise, $TZ = I_W$ but $ZT \neq I_V$)?

Comment: Are $V,W$ finite-dimensional?

Comment: It is not quite clear from the question: do you assume that $T^{-1}$ exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible.  For instance, take $W = \Bbb R^2, V = \Bbb R$,
$$
Z(x,y) = x
$$
If we define $T(x) = (x,0)$, then we indeed have $ZT = I_{V}$ but $TZ \neq I_W$.  The reverse happens if we exchange the roles of $Z$ and $T$.

For a fixed $V,W$ with $\dim(V) = \dim(W) < \infty$, [no such pair exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852/81360).

In the infinite dimensional setting, the [left and right shift operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator#Sequences) are an example of such a pair for which $V = W$.

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=1=I_1$  but $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&0\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\neq I_2$

It’s also worth pointing out that (for transformations over fields, anyway) that theorem only holds when $V$ and $W$ have equal dimension.

Answer (score 1):

If W, V are not the same dimension...e.g. suppose $V$ is $\mathbb R^3$ and $W$ is $\mathbb R^2$

Then there can exist $T, U$ such that $TU = I_W$  but since the rank of $T$ has rank less than $3$ it is not possible for $UT$ to be rank $3$ and be an the identity matrix of $\mathbb R^3$